# application.run(new form1()) name of form1

Tags: c#

In a Windows form application:
Can i set porpertys (eg Name) to the form1 **instance** my application.run method creates?

I tried a few things like this:

```
application.run(new form1("somename"))
```

Is it possible to give a "name" or any other porperty to form1?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to read some c# tutorial. Using parameters and properties is about the most basic concepts you will find.

Comment: I agree.  Start with the basics and do some tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice.
So is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that should have been implied by my comment. Sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: See [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You can’t set attributes at run time at all. You can change values of properties and fields. (It May be good idea to read on “what  attributes are in c#”)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Who's talking about adding attributes at runtime?

Comment: The the question refers to properties as attributes, hence the confusion

Answer (score -3):

Start assigning it to a variable to keep a reference, ie,

```
var aForm = new form1("somename");
```

then assign properties

```
aForm.SomeProperty = SomeValue;
aForm.SomeSetting = SomeSettingValue;
```

Then run it

```
application.run(aForm);
```

Comment: This assumes the OP knows how to use properties and parameters, and by the question it should be clear this is not true

Comment: .. and also assumes the form has a custom constructor defined that takes the name as a parameter.